# disable add to cart if custom options are required.Magento

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

in my current product view http://goo.gl/pgdoUl I have all required custom options with a pop up windows that show up in case the value is wrong eg. Track/Pole Length - Finished Curtain Drop. If in the text file all the information are wrong it's still possible to add to cart the product.
How in this case it's possible to disable add to cart?

Comment: u are using anytheme?

Answer (score 0):

Currently magento uses prototype/validation.js which is the default way magento uses validations. What you need to do here is write jQuery or plain JavaScript function to validate all your entries and on the bind this function to the click event of add to cart button, only if the validation succeeds the add to cart (which is a form) should get submitted.